# Unable to connect to TFS 2010 with VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, team-explorer

I'm experiencing some problems with connection to TFS2010 with Visual Studio 2010 in https.

I have installed:

1. Visual Studio 2010
2. Team Explorer 2010
3. Visual Studio 2010 SP1
4. KB 2581206

but I'm getting TFS 31002 error:

[image]

Do I need to install something else?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: but where TFS is installed? do you have login and password to it?

Comment: Yes, I have login and password, but it doesn't prompt it to me. I also correctly reach the following url: https://.../Services/v1.0/ServerStatus.asmx

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the computer was in the same domain as the TFS server, so the credetials that were passed to TFS were those of the user logged that are invalid to connect to TFS.
So I solved removing computer from domain and now credential are correctly prompted.